# How do I stop the leaves from curling on my Stromanthe "Burle Marx"?

Tags: watering, leaves

The leaves on my Stromanthe "Burle Marx" are all curling vertically.  I usually water it from the bottom on a bed of stones but I wonder if the water standing on the stones has caused it to be over-watered.  I poured out the water that was standing and am now hoping it will come back to life.

Is it likely to, and what is the best way to prevent this curling?

Answer (score 1):

Leaves curl for various reasons like too much or too less sun light, overwatering, extreme underwatering, lack of humidity.

I suggest to loosen up the soil and place the plant near moderate sunlight source.

Also take care that its soil remains moist (but not wet). This could help it grow better.

Answer (score -1):

Leaves curling may occur due to viral attack. Please ensure that how many plants are infected with leaf curl.

And also check under side of the each curling leaves and find out any presence of insects.

Can you share some picture both upper and lower sides of the curling leaves.

Thank you.